# How to convert URL query string into URL parameters in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, forms

I have a form that sends a get request to a `/player/` route. When I click the submit button, the URL looks something like this:

```
https://examle.com/player?username=johndoe
```

I want the URL to look like this:

```
https://examle.com/player/johndoe
```

The username will then be passed as a parameter to a controller method:

```
public function player(string $username)
{
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: may be you could intercept the form and then send the request to your custom route from the front end after building the url? or you could redirect from the controller.

Comment: You need to make parameterize route man... See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-and-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple route for it to accept username

```php
Route::post("/player/{username}", [PlayerController::class, "player"])
->name("player.submit");
```

The use the url to that accept username

```php
<form action"{{ route("player.submit", ["username" => $username]) }}">
...
</form>
```

I think this is basic, you can read on https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-and-dependency-injection

If you need get, you can use other url, then redirect to the player location using same route() function. I assume that you want to submit data, so I put post as example

Comment: that's not what the OP is asking for if I understood correctly !!

Comment: @OMiShah He want the username to be on the url right.. you must set it on the route.. to be able to have that url... if you don't have that parameterize route, you will get the same url even using the route() function. You can try it..

Comment: here ``$username`` is not known, think of a search form where the user enters an username and then submits the form then the username value is sent (appended to URL in case of GET request).

Comment: I just giving example, as he doesn't give any form that is available... If you can improve, then improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the way that HTML form operates. You can consider using jquery like below:

In web.php

```
Route::get('player/{username?}', [PlayerController::class, 'search'])->name('user.search')
```

In view:

```
<input name="user_name" id="user_name"/>
<a href="{{route('user.search')}}" id="btnSearch">Search</a>

<script>
   let href = "{{route('user.search'}}"
   $("#user_name ").on('change', function(e) {
       $("#btnSearch").attr(href, href + "/" + $(this).val())
   })
</script>
```